# However, there were other interactions with this mock:

Tags: android, unit-testing, rx-java, retrofit2, mvp

So i have problem, this is my presenter code :

```
@Override
public void login(String phone, String password) {
    loginView.showProgress();
    compositeSubscription.clear();

    Subscription subscription = service.login(phone,password)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(data -> {
                //Log.d("Login", new Gson().toJson(data));
                loginView.hideProgress();
                if(data.getSt()==1)
                {
                    saveDataPartner(data.getData().getId_hos(), data.getData().getName(), data.getData().getEmail(), data.getData().getPhone(), data.getData().getAvatar());
                    loginView.navigateToMainMenu();
                }
                else {
                    loginView.showMessage(data.getMsg());
                }
            }, error -> {
                loginView.hideProgress();
                loginView.showMessage(ErrorUtils.getErrorMessage(error));
            });
}
```

and i want to test this with this code :

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    RxAndroidPlugins.getInstance().registerSchedulersHook(new RxAndroidSchedulersHook() {
        @Override
        public Scheduler getMainThreadScheduler() {
            return Schedulers.immediate();
        }
    });
}

@After
public void tearDown() {
    RxAndroidPlugins.getInstance().reset();
}

@Test
public void clickBtnLogin() {

    User user = new User();
    user.setName("aa");
    ResultAPIUser<User> ru = new ResultAPIUser<User>();

    ru.setData(user);
    ru.setMsg("example message");
    ru.setSt(1);

    when(service.login("aa","aa")).thenReturn(Observable.just(ru));

    loginPresenter.login("aa","aa");

    verify(loginView).showProgress();
    verify(loginView).hideProgress();
    verify(loginView).navigateToMainMenu();
}
```

so I set the value of st is 1, and I think it should be fine. But I get this :

```
Wanted but not invoked:
loginView.hideProgress();
-> at     hos.wellhos.com.hosapps.login.LoginPresenterTest.clickBtnLogin(LoginPresenterTest.java:79)

 However, there were other interactions with this mock:
 loginView.setPresenter(
     hos.wellhos.com.hosapps.login.LoginPresenter@4313f5bc
 );
 -> at hos.wellhos.com.hosapps.login.LoginPresenter.<init>    (LoginPresenter.java:43)
```

Anybody can help me solve this, and I think there is tricky problem for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely to be a threading issue.  Your `Observable` is subscribing on `Schedulers.io`
Even though you then switch to the main thread so process the results this will take time.  As such your verify statements are being processed before the subscription completes.

There are a couple of ways that you could deal with this:

**Dynamic Schedulers**

Instead of passing in the required scheduler directly to your `subscribeOn` & `observeOn` methods you can define member variables which hold these for you:

```
Scheduler ioScheduler;
Scheduler mainThreadScheduler;
```

and use them in the `observeOn`/`subscribeOn` statments:

```
.subscribeOn(ioScheduler)
.observeOn(mainThreadScheduler)
```

You can then set these as you do any other dependency in the class constructor.  For production code you would set them as the normal `Schedulers.io()` & `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()` however in your Test code you would set them both to `Schedulers.immediate()` (which just returns a Scheduler for the current thread).

**RxJavaHooks**

Introduced in RxJava 1.1.7 there is a util class called `RxJavaHooks` which allows you to hook into several parts of the lifecycle of RxJava.  One of these hooks is the `setOnIOScheduler()` method.  This allows you to change which `Scheduler` is returned by `Schedulers.io`.

In your case you want to change it to `Schedulers.immediate()`:

```
RxJavaHooks.setOnIOScheduler(scheduler -> Schedulers.immediate());
```

Once you've done your test you then need to call:

```
RxJavaHooks.reset();
```

This just puts everything back to normal so that this change doesn't interfere with other tests you run elsewhere.

Comment: thx, but I actually implement RxJavaHooks like your solution in setUp and tearDown, I will edit myPost hehehe

Comment: Haha, so you have.  It looks like you've only changed the mainThreadScheduler though...have you tried adding an override for Schedulers.io?

Comment: hahaha thx for your answer, as your say on Dynamic Schedulers, I just create interface class and I create 2 class for baseSchedulers and immediateScheduller so I just use immediateScheduller for the test and it work ^_^, thx dude. But I have a question why Log can affect the Test result ? so when I uncomment Log.d (you can see my code on onNext of observable) then that will trigger onError ?

Comment: Glad you got it working!  The only reason I can see that the Log might trigger an `onError` is if GSON throws an error for some reason.